# Error Deserialising Protocol Buffer messages when publishing through Cloud PubSub

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to publish protobuf messages over Cloud Pub Sub, the issue i am having is serialising and deserialising the protobuf message to and from a byte string that is required to send through pubsub.

Below is the relevant part of my code, i pass a Protobuf object to publish_price and from there you can see i try to publish the message after serialising it. The issue from what i can make comes at the deserialising end after the result is returned in the callback method.

```
 # # Publish price
def publish_price(price_obj):
    new_price_obj = price_obj.SerializeToString()
    

    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, new_price_obj)
    future.add_done_callback(get_callback(future, new_price_obj))

def get_callback(f, data):
        def callback(f):
            try:
                print(str(f.result(), 'utf-8'))
                # print(f.result())
                
            except:  # noqa
                print(data.FromString())
                print("Please handle {} for {}.".format(f.exception(), data))

        return callback
```

Below is the relevant error message

```
Exception in thread Thread-CommitBatchPublisher:
[server] Traceback (most recent call last):
[server]   File "/app/app.py", line 39, in callback
[server]     print(str(f.result(), 'utf-8'))
[server] TypeError: decoding str is not supported
[server]
[server] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[server]
[server] Traceback (most recent call last):
[server]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
[server]     self.run()
[server]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
[server]     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
[server]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py", line 292, in _commit
[server]     future.set_result(message_id)
[server]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py", line 159, in set_result
[server]     self._trigger()
[server]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/futures.py", line 186, in _trigger
[server]     callback(self)
[server]   File "/app/app.py", line 43, in callback
[server]     print(data.ParseFromString())
[server] AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'ParseFromString'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `data` is the bytestring object that you want to parse. `bytes` is a class from the Python standard library, it has no knowledge of protocol buffers and no `ParseFromString` method. That's a method that protobuf classes have.

`FromString` is a method declared in the *proto* class. Assuming `ResponseProto` is the type you want to parse:

```
def parse_response(data: bytes):
    response = ResponseProto.FromString(data)
    return response
```